# Jquery flytocart animation image getting stuck

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, shopping-cart

I have a flytocart animation that is not disappearing after the intial add. Any ideas? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53LeQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

hide it on callback cant give you more cos of there is no code in you'r question and we need more descriptions

please add more description